# Copyright symbol in rdlc reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

I want to print a copyright symbol in rdlc report textbox
how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just using the © character? This works fine:

[image]

I just added a Text Box with the expression `© Copyright Symbol ©`.

Comment: Get it from Windows Character Map, use Alt+0169, or just CTRL+C it from the answer above. It's just a standard character.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this helpful, please consider upvoting and/or setting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any nvarchar symbol in the database and then just bind it to report.

```
 =Fields!CurrencySymbol.Value
```